# 'contains' and 'starts with' cannot match text with a character after a hyphen

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Google Sheets queries cannot match text using `contains` or `starts with` when there the text to match contains a hyphen, and the hyphen is not the last character in the text to match. Am I doing something wrong? If not, is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14c0VDK8L5D4yxOvHhyEM2aYiDrMivrCgukeQbkpSFUI/edit?usp=sharing).

`"select count(A) where A starts with '2021-'"` will return the count of matching results.

`"select count(A) where A starts with '2021-0'"`, on the other hand, always claims there are no matching results even if there actually are.

Answer (score 1):

The `query()` function happily matches *text* that contains hyphens.

When you use the `contains` operator, data in columns of type `date` gets automatically converted to text in the `yyyy-m-d` format, lacking leading zeros, regardless of their original format.

You can get what you ask for by converting the dates to text before feeding them to `query()` like this:

`=arrayformula( query( trim(A2:A8), "select count(Col1) where Col1 starts with '2021-0' ", 0 ) )`

But this is not a very good way to find dates before October, because it depends on the date format in the spreadsheet remaining `yyyy-mm-dd`. A better solution would not rely on the format, like this:

`=query(A2:A8, "select count(A) where year(A) = 2021 and month(A)+1 < 10", 0)`

Months are zero-indexed, hence the `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

The values in Column A below the header (`A1`) are date values, not text values.
If you want to use Google Query language text operators, among other ways to do get the required results, you might convert the date values to text values by using `TO_TEXT` Google Sheets built-in function

Instead of

```
=query(A2:A7,"select count(A) where A starts with '2021-0'",0)
```

you might use

```
=ArrayFormula(query(TO_TEXT(A2:A7),"select count(Col1) where Col1 starts with '2021-0'",0))
```

Please note that `A` was replaced by `Col1` in the second parameter of `query` and the use of `ArrayFormula`

Answer (score -1):

It is NOT a bug.
It works as expected.

The issue is that dates are numbers while `starts with` and `contains` look for text.

You can see that in the following example where column `B` is an exact copy of column `A` but formatted as text.

[image]

Dates are scalar functions. You can read about them [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions)
Also under the `where clause` it is mentioned

> The where clause also supports some more complex string comparison operators. These operators take two strings as arguments; any non-string arguments (for example, dates or numbers) will be converted to strings before comparison.

So an expression like `2021-` has no meaning as a number.

To look for the year use

```
=query(A2:A9,"select count(A) where A starts with year(date '2021-02-05')",0)
```